# Moving data out of salesforce for customer facing apps

Tags: web-apps, software-development, database, api

There is a lot of words here, feel free to skip to the third paragraph if you don't want to read them all. Cheers!

My company currently uses Salesforce very heavily. We use it for everything: accounts receiving, invoicing, database admin, application database, business processes manager, integrations, and so on. 
As nice as it is to have everything in one place, it's very hard to manage and not very expandable since there are somewhat severe limits on processing power, number of queries, and API calls.

Specifically we have two medium sized web apps that are hosted on Visualforce pages that our customers access. These web apps are not staff facing. They use AngularJS for the frontend and Javascript Remoting to get data. Not a bad way to do it, but there isn't any source control, the file management is cumbersome, the apps aren't very fast, and the deploy method(changsesets) for Salesforce is slow and painful.

I'm looking for ways to move the data pertinent to our customer facing apps out of salesforce. We still need our admin staff to be able to manage the data, run reports and so on, but unfortunately me and my team don't have the velocity to rebuild all the features needed on our own.

Does anyone have any suggestions on software or methods that we can use to move data out of Salesforce and still allow administration of it?

Feel free to ask questions! Thanks for any help in advance :)